Quantative/Statistical comparison between unequal corpora
I have created a corpus of 400.000 words, consisting exclusively of governmental administrative documents. I am focusing on the usage of rare words and i want to prove that my corpus has increased frequency of those words compared to other available corpora. The problem is that the other 3 corpora measure up to 3 million words (only newspapers), 20 million words (mixed corpus), and 2.3 billion words (webcorpus via sketchengine) respectively. Could i compare the absolute frequencies of those words between those corpora in any statistical way, or it is impossible to solely rely on quantitative data, taking into consideration how different is the size of the other 3 corpora? Thank you in advance.
